# How to get child keys from Firebase Database (Angular2)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-template, angularfire2

My Code (pictures below):

```
this.allStatisticsRef = afDatabase.list(`data/users/${this.currentUserID}/statistics`);
  this.allStatisticData = this.allStatisticsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
});
```

So my `key`value is "2016" and "2017". How I get the child keys "8" and "9"? Anyone an idea?

**What I exactly expect:**

To use the data like this in my view: `{{ data.key.childkey.value }}`
I´m building a list separated by year and months. The example above would be: `{{ data.year.month.values }}` or as result `{{ data['2017']['8']['hours'] }}`

I want to write the view like this:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data of allStatisticData | async">
<ion-list-header>{{ data.key }} (Year)</ion-list-header>
<ion-item>
  <ion-item-divider>{{ data.childKey }} (Month)</ion-item-divider>
  {{ value }} (Data)
</ion-item>
```

[image: Firebase Data structure] 
[image: Result - Object]

Comment: Err... `allStatisticsRef.child('2017/8')`? Update your question to include results you expect.

Comment: I´ve edited my post with my expected results. :)